# Audio should play before being redirected to a link

Tags: javascript, css, html, audio

I am new to website development and am learning that independently. In my website i am having a Audio nested within a button at the top of the page. If the user muted the audio, the rest of the navigation links will not have that music played. else each time the user clicks a link, the audio will be played before being redirected to another link.

My HTML code is as such:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"><span id="facebook" onclick="playLink(this.id)">facebook</span></a>
```

my java code is as such:

```
function playLink(id)
{

if(audio1.muted==true && id=="facebook")
{
 window.location.href="https://www.facebook.com/?stype=lo&jlou=AfdeVGNZ2wkOmLR2JKTDO5TQxnERQXFcGGG5gBl3mieEaFJq-_rbey251tojJmP3jetCtclLhIYstrSsHlonyLoa&smuh=44193&lh=Ac_NtNBBW6lW7Cwg";
}

if(audio1.muted==false && id=="facebook")
{
  audio1.play();
  alert("1");
  if(audio1.ended)
  window.location.href="https://www.facebook.com/?stype=lo&jlou=AfdeVGNZ2wkOmLR2JKTDO5TQxnERQXFcGGG5gBl3mieEaFJq-_rbey251tojJmP3jetCtclLhIYstrSsHlonyLoa&smuh=44193&lh=Ac_NtNBBW6lW7Cwg;
 }
 }
```

the problem is the background sound plays and navigates successfully after the ending of the clip, only if i add an alert after audio1.play(). else it plays the sound but does not navigate to the linked page. how do i fix it?

Any help is appreciated. thanks!

P.S: the *a* is part of the bootstrap nav bar.

Comment: have you tried `setTimeout` instead of `alert`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. it works perfectly with setTimeout. but I am still wondering why just  if(audio.ended) is not working on its own without a setTimeout/setInterval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, use some time lapse using `setTimeout` as,

```
if(audio1.muted==false && id=="facebook")
{
  audio1.play();
  //alert("1");
  setTimeout(function(){
            if(audio1.ended){
             window.location.href="https://www.facebook.com/?stype=lo&jlou=AfdeVGNZ2wkOmLR2JKTDO5TQxnERQXFcGGG5gBl3mieEaFJq-_rbey251tojJmP3jetCtclLhIYstrSsHlonyLoa&smuh=44193&lh=Ac_NtNBBW6lW7Cwg;
            }
      }, 200);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. it works well with a time lapse.

Comment: wonder if it's about multiple events getting fired in succession. Don't know how `audio1`'s events are firing. to be honest, your alert statement was the clue for using setTimeout. you can do so in future. Also, please accept the answer if you feel it helped. thanks :)

Comment: @self-learner one more thing, avoid doing these `if(audio1.muted==false)` or  `if(audio1.muted==true)`, rather use, `if(!audio1.muted)` and `if(audio1.muted)` as the return type of `audio1.muted` is anyways a boolean.